# ¿Cómo crear una tabla indicando el número de filas y columnas desde diferentes input usando jQuery?

Tags: jquery, table, input

tengo el siguiente código html que es para crear una tabla por medio de inputs

```
<div>
    <label>Número de columnas<input type="number" name="columna"></label>
    <label>Número de filas<input type="number" name="fila"></label>
    <button type="button" id="crear">Crear</button>
    <table id="tabla"></table>
</div>
```

El siguiente código jQuery lo intento realizar para que al colocar un cierto número en filas y columnas me arroje una tabla con esa cantidad de filas y columnas pero no entiendo cual es el error que tengo

```
    `$(function(){
    var fila = $("#rows").val()
    var columna = $("#cols").val()
    $("#crear").click(function(){
    tabla=$("#tabla")
            tabla+=for (var i=1;i=fila;i++){
            tabla+="<tr>";
                    for (var x=1;x=columna;i++){
                        tabla+="<td>""</td>";
                    }
                tabla+="</tr>"
            }
        });
    })`
```

Comment: Te faltó el javascript

Comment: Soy nuevo aquí, aún no sé cómo usar la pag, ya agregue lo que tengo

Comment: Ese código que nos muestras funciona? o qué resultado te da?

Comment: No, no me funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

La instrucción **let** declara una variable de alcance local con ámbito de bloque(block scope), la cual, opcionalmente, puede ser inicializada con algún valor.

**var** es una variable global existe tanto fuera como dentro!

```js
$(function(){
    $("#crear").on("click",function(){
    // debe leer los valores luego del click no antes!
    let fila = parseInt($("#fila").val()); // hacemos un cast a entero
    let columna = parseInt($("#columna").val()); // hacemos un cast a entero
    let resultado = '<table style="width:100%">';
    let tabla= $("#tabla");
    if(!fila || !columna){
       alert(`debes especificar las filas y las colummnas!`);
       return; // evitamos que se ejecute si es 0 o undefined
    }
    
    for (let i=1; i <= fila; i++){
            resultado+="<tr>";
            for (let x=1;x <= columna;x++){
                resultado+=`<td>${x}</td>`;
              }
             resultado+="</tr>";
            }
         // agregamos al dom
         tabla.html(resultado + "</table>");
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>Número de columnas<input type="number" name="columna" id="columna"></label>
    <label>Número de filas<input type="number" name="fila" id="fila"></label>
    <button type="button" id="crear">Crear</button>
    <table id="tabla"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué indicas con let?

Comment: @SalvadorDurán ya edite para responderte a la pregunta!

Comment: Perdón, otra cosa que no había notado bien
`<td>${x}</td>`
esa línea como la explicas, entiendo que hace, pero no entiendo como

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$("#crear").on("click",function(){
// debe leer los valores luego del click no antes!
let fila = parseInt($("#fila").val()); // hacemos un cast a entero
let columna = parseInt($("#columna").val()); // hacemos un cast a entero
let resultado = '<table style="width:100%">';
let tabla= $("#tabla");
if(!fila || !columna){
   alert(`debes especificar las filas y las colummnas!`);
   return; // evitamos que se ejecute si es 0 o undefined
}

for (let i=1; i <= fila; i++){
        resultado+="<tr>";
        for (let x=1;x <= columna;x++){
            resultado+=`<td>${x}</td>`;
          }
         resultado+="</tr>";
        }
     // agregamos al dom
     tabla.html(resultado + "</table>");
    });



    // intento hacer lo siguiente para crear un botón que agregue una columna nueva al final pero solo me agrega un número cómo puedo hacerlo?
    $("#addcol_fin").click(function(){
            $("#tabla").append(i)
        });
```

})